# Unable to disable SSLv3 on WSO2 Carbon 4.0.6

Tags: wso2, poodle-attack, wso2-esb

Due the possibility of Poodle Attack, I'm trying to disable the SSLv3 on WSO2 ESB-4.6.0.

Following the [oficial documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Configuring+Transport+Level+Security#ConfiguringTransportLevelSecurity-Changingthepass-throughtransportconfigs3):

Open [product_home]/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml

Find the transportReceiver configuration element for `org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener`

If you are using JDK 1.7 - add the following parameter under transportReceiver.

```
<parameter name="HttpsProtocols">TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2</parameter>
```

Save and start the server

It did not worked! I guess it's because the carbon version of ESB-4.6.0 is 4.0.6 instead of 4.2.0 as described in documentation.
The `java -jar TestSSLServer.jar localhost 8243` output is:

```
Supported versions: SSLv3 TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
Deflate compression: no
Supported cipher suites (ORDER IS NOT SIGNIFICANT):
  SSLv3
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  (TLSv1.0: idem)
  (TLSv1.1: idem)
  TLSv1.2
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

So, my question is: How to disable the SSLv3 on Carbon 4.0.6?

Answer (score 1):

We can get this done via JVM level ciphers by using Java's 'jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms' property in java.security file.

It can be done by using values such as following to the property:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, MD5, DESede, DH keySize < 2048, RSA keySize < 2048
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK for wso2 esb 4.6.0 you can disable the SSLv3 for port 9443(servlet port) only by following the official document.The doc is applicable only for carbon 4.2.0 based products